# Finding all possible combinations recursively in python

Tags: python, function, recursion

Given a certain number of lists, each of which represents the time it takes to go from one shop to all others, and a list containing a sequence of time intervals, is there a way to find all possible routes between shops using recursivity?

For example

```
list_of_shops = [shop1, shop2, shop3, shop4] 
# Index for this list and the one below are the same

list_of_time_it_takes = [[0, 2, 1, 4], [2, 0, 1, 4], [2, 1, 0, 4], [1, 2, 3, 0]]
# the 0 indicates the index of the shop. It takes 0 minutes to reach the shop from itself.

list_of_time_intervals = [0, 2, 2]
```

Shops can only be visited once.
We can see that 3 shops have been visited at 2 minute intervals and that the possible routes are:

> shop4 > shop2 > shop1
>
> shop3 > shop1 > shop2

Is there a way to obtain the above output using a recursive algorithm similar to the recursive method explained on this page > [A simple recursion explanation](http://www.dotnetperls.com/recursion-python/) ? And if not, what would be the best way to obtain the above output?

Comment: How are the time intervals significant? How are we supposed to use them? Also, the syntax in your list of time intervals is incorrect. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I edited it so it is clearer - Time intervals might be a bit misleading. It's the time shown on the clock when a person enters a shop. For the sake of the exercices, I'm ignoring the time it takes to shop. So in this example, the person enters a shop (0), and two minutes later (2) he enters another shop, and 2 minutes after that (2) he enters a third shop.
That's what I meant.

Comment: Why not just use something out of `itertools` like `product`, `combinations`, or `permutations`?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann As mentioned, I am trying to learn recursion, so I have to create a recursive algorithm in this case. Also, I believe recursion is  superior in terms of efficiency in this case, but I may be wrong since I don't know much about it.

Comment: Just so you know, this is the Traveling Salesman Problem, and you're basically not going to solve it.

Comment: @DefinitelyBlitzkrank: Tree traversal (where recursion is natural) and factorial are *much* better than trying to solve an NP-complete problem.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Would you be kind enough to elaborate? I am not exactly trying to find the shortest route, but just all possible combinations. Using recursion to find all possible combinations that lead to a sum for example is quite natural, so I thought I could use it to find all possible combinations in this case. Was I wrong to think that?

Comment: The number of combinations grows exponentially, so it's not something you'd ever do in real life. By the time you get an interesting number of nodes, it gets incredibly slow. The reason I'm suggesting something like implementing a binary search tree is trees are inherently recursive--the the left and right subtree are complete trees, themselves.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann So in my case is using trees better than using itertools? Though I have no experience with trees and have only basic knowledge of the concept, I will probably resort to using itertools anyway.

Comment: This is not TSP, for starters the intervals constrain the problem significantly

Comment: @Pyetras Well thanks to the intervals, there is a significantly smaller number of possible routes. That being said, I still don't know if there's a way of obtaining the desired output, recursively, or using another method.

Comment: @Pyetras It may constrain the problem, but it still appears to me to be exponential growth as you add times between shops that occur in the list of intervals (as opposed to the raw list of shops). Granted, it's considerably slower than before, but still ultimately exponential growth.

Comment: Still the TSP is about finding and *optimizing* a *cycle*, nothing like this here. Also a NP-hard problema are not unsolvable, they are just not possible to solve in reasonable time for the general case. Here, since we are looking for all solutions (there can be O((shops-1)^intervals) solutions) we can iterate through all of them in linear time

Comment: @Pyetras Agreed that TSP's optimization isn't done here, but the guarantee that you've found the optimal solution in TSP is discovery of all valid routes, tracking the minimum route the whole way. (i.e., the difficult part of TSP isn't determining which of the routes is the mimima) The problem at hand shares needing to discover all valid routes and thusly echoes TSP appropriately.  I also think your algorithm runtime analysis is incorrect -- the exponent needs to be the *count* of intervals in actual routes which match (count in `list_of_time_it_takes`), not the raw count of intervals.

Comment: Big O notation is about the worst case scenario. Worst case here is all intervals == 1 and all distances between shops == 1. The guarantee you mention is not necessary, it's just the naive solution, there are algorithms for TSP that can do significantly better than O(n!). Back to OPs problem: sure, you can't iterate a list faster than O(length(list))

Comment: I mis-spoke when I said runtime analysis -- I meant to say that I think your total number of solutions is incorrect. I interpreted your parenthetical statement "(there can be O((shops-1)^intervals) solutions)" correctly, but when I answered, I switched to a 'big-o means runtime analysis' rather than raw 'worst case' as you had intended. I agree that runtime of this problem is on the order of O(n!).

Comment: I never said that it's an O(n!) problem, I'm sticking with my original upper bound estimation. I'm afraid I fail to see your point anymore.

Comment: @Definitely Blitzkrank this problem can be solved with recursion, for example with a technique called backtracking. Look up the N-Queens problem on wikipedia and try to go from there. You should also be aware that the number of possible solutions can grow pretty big, so it may not be feasible to see all of them.

Comment: @Pyetras Thank you! I will look into that and post it as an answer if I manage to make it work.